# Expressing doing something in case of/as a precaution for some other possible occurrence

Tags: translation, english-to-japanese

I see that 「念のために」 is an expression that means "just in case" in general, but how does one express "I'm going to do A in case B happens"?

For example, "I'm writing in pencil in case I make a mistake." Would that be translated simply as 「間違えるから、鉛筆で書いています。」, or is there a better way to capture the nuance of doing something expressly for the purpose of insurance against some other possible occurrence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "I'm writing in pencil in case I make a mistake."

How about...

「間違え**てもいいように**、鉛筆で書いています。」

or maybe...

「間違える**といけないから**、鉛筆で書いています。」

---

Example:

雨が降ってもいいように、傘を持っていきなさい。
雨が降るといけないから、傘を持っていきなさい。
Take your umbrella in case it rains.

Comment: or maybe... 「間違えるかもしれないから、鉛筆で書いています。」「雨が降るかもしれないから、傘を持っていきなさい。」

Comment: Thanks. Am I correct in thinking the first one means "I'm writing in pencil so that it's okay if I make a mistake" (i.e. mitigating the consequences), and the second "Because it would be bad if I made a mistake, I am writing in pencil" (i.e. mitigating the cause)?

Comment: @db2 はい、 yes, precisely!

Comment: Hooray, the studying is actually working! :D